# Manual unlocking done before notifying

Tags: c++, multithreading

Thanks to the book of the Doctor Scott Meyers, page 263, I recently discovered `condition_variable`, so I had to search about it [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to study it more.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

I have several questions on it, because I think on it since several days, and I still did not understand.

My questions are about this piece of code :

```
// Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
// the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
lk.unlock();
cv.notify_one();
```

1) I do not understand what the author of the cppreference means by that comment and by "the waiting thread, only to block again" because I don't know even how to translate it, and

2) Which threads it denotes exactly, and why in particular.

3) Does it denote the thread_worker or the main thread (parent) ?

4) What they chose to do that ?

And what does it change if the authors notify first and then manually unlock ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a minor and usually irrelevant optimization. The concern arises because each thread that wakes up after a call to `notify` or `notify_all` has to lock the mutex before it is allowed to proceed. If the call to `unlock` occurs after the call to `notify_one` (or to `notify`), the thread(s) that wake up will have to wait until after the calling thread unlocks it. If the call to `unlock` is made before the notify call then one awakened thread can get the mutex immediately.

Comment: I posted a new comment and I have completed my first post

Comment: Thank you Pete Becker.

Could you explain to me pricesely, what does it mean, when the author of cppreference writes :

Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)

in the example

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

What does it mean "the waiting thread only to block again"

Because i try to understand it in french.

Which thread does it denote in the example of cppreference ? Is it the main thread or the thread_worker ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The main thread blocks on the condition variable, waiting for the worker thread to finish. When the worker thread is finished it calls `notify_one` to wake up the main thread. The concern is that the main thread might be inconvenienced if the mutex isn't immediately available.

Comment: Finally,  I think I understood, please correct me dear Pete if I am not right :  1) the mutex cannot be shared between 2 threads at the same time      2) in the sentence, "the waiting thread only to block again" denotes the main thread.    3) so if the notify is before the "unlock", there is a first spurious wake up of the main thread before the std::mutex is not yet got again by the main thread. But after the unlock, there is a second wake up , which is the good one as and the main thread resumes as the mutex is acquired by the main thread at that moment.     What do you think ?

Comment: A spurious wake up is something entirely different. A condition variable is allowed to release a thread without a call to `notify..l`. That’s a spurious wake up, and it’s why code typically runs a loop: `while (!condition) condition_variable.wait();`.

Comment: When a thread gets released by a condition variable there are two steps: waking up the thread, and locking the mutex. If the mutex is locked for any reason the thread will block until the thread that holds lock releases it.